# I am trying to make an slideshow only with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an slideshow only with php for school i did all the coding but somthing dosen't work ok with the counter.
Is there an easyer solution then what i did ?
Things go wrong when you hit "back" it jumps one picture, but was the only way i wass able to make it . ( i know it can be made with jquery much easyer)

```html
<?php
 $nex = isset ($_POST["nex"]);
 $prev = isset($_POST["prev"]);
 $hid1 = isset($_POST["hid1"]) ? $_POST["hid1"]: 0;
 
 if ($hid1 < 6 & $nex){
 $hid1 ++;
 echo '<img src="imagini/nvidia'.$hid1,'.jpg">';
 }
 
 elseif ($hid1 == 6){
 $hid1=0;
 echo '<img src="imagini/nvidia'.$hid1,'.jpg">';
 }
 
 elseif ($prev & $hid1 > 0){
  $hid1 --;
  echo '<img src="imagini/nvidia'.$hid1,'.jpg">';
 }
 elseif ($hid1 == 0){
 $hid1 = 5;
 echo '<img src="imagini/nvidia'.$hid1,'.jpg">';
 }
?>
```

```html
<html>
 
 <body>
 
  <form  method="post">
   
   <input name="hid1" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hid1;?>">
   <input name="prev" type="submit" value="Previous">
   <input name="nex" type="submit" value="Next">
   
   
  
  </form>





 </body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You have to controll all the post variables

this should work

```
if ( $_POST ) {

        $nex = isset($_POST["nex"]) ? $_POST['nex']: 0; 
        $prev = isset($_POST["prev"])? $_POST['prev']: 0; 
        $hid1 = isset($_POST["hid1"]) ? $_POST["hid1"]: 0;


            if ( $nex ) {
                $hid1++;
            }else{
                $hid1--;
            }

            if ( $hid1 > 6 ) {
                $hid1 = 0; 
            }elseif ( $hid1 < 0 ){
                $hid1 = 6; 
            }

        }else{
            $hid1 = 0; 
        }

        echo '<img src="imagini/nvidia'.$hid1.'.jpg">';
```